# string.Format return empty string

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

Is there a way to get `string.Format` to always return an empty string?

```
    string.Format("", DateTime.Now);
```

3rd party component lets us pass no more than a format string.  The empty string idea doesn't work.  Was hoping there might be another less obvious way.  I do not deny that the below code works (answers), it is just that I can't reprogram said 3rd party component.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just String.Empty?

Comment: The code shown should do as much...

Comment: @KyleC: see amended question above

Comment: @sgtz Why doesn't empty string format work? And can you specify different formats for different arrg list?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: there must be some hand coded logic by the 3rd party (like string.EmptyOrNull) that sets it to a default.  Possibly I'm asking the impossible from this angle and need to look at an IValueConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
string.Format(" ", DateTime.Now);
```

At least that's the way to trick the 3rd party software into giving the desired result.

Comment: Although the empty format string in a string.Format *does* format a value as blank, how it works in practice will depend on any application code that consumes the format string before passing it to a string.Format. Ignoring a null/blank format string is a reasonable action, hence a single space working for you. This trick works in ASP.Net MVC HTML Helpers too, i.e. if you want the benefits of using a TextBoxFor but don't want to render the value then a " " format string will blank the value.

Answer (score 2):

`string.Format("{0}", string.Empty)`?

Comment: I should say that date will always have a valid date in it... and that all that I can do is pass a 3rd party library is the format string.  I'm trying to trick it.

Comment: Your example should work just fine: string.Format("", DateTime.Now) - I just checked in a simple Console App and it resulted in a blank string.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
string.Format(string.Empty, other, useless, parameters);
```

Comment: Wokay, but how is this essentially different from the OP's code...?

Comment: @sehe For a task this simple, it is hard to come up with anything different, let alone *essentially* different. The only difference is referencing string.Empty explicitly, and the OP requested a return of string.Empty.